# How to compute the derivative of the total loss wrt external trainable parameters?

Tags: neural-networks, backpropagation, derivative, multitask-learning

I was just curious how external trainable parameters are updated. The challenge is to compute the derivative, the rest is handled by the optimiser.

I assumed a simple DNN as follows:
$$\hat{y} =\sigma(W_2 \sigma(W_1 X + b_1) + b_2)$$

where the symbols have their usual meaning. The full forward pass is as follows:

$$ a^{(0)} = X$$
$$a^{(i)} = \sigma(z^{(i)})$$
$$ z^{(i)} = W_i a^{(i-1)} + b_i$$
$$\hat{y} = a^{(L)} $$

The derivative of the loss wrt the inputs would be:
$$ \frac{\partial J}{\partial X} = 
   \frac{\partial J}{\partial a^{(2)}} 
   \frac{\partial a^{(2)}}{\partial z^{(2)}} 
   \frac{\partial z^{(2)}}{\partial a^{(1)}} 
   \frac{\partial a^{(1)}}{\partial z^{(1)}} 
   \frac{\partial z^{(1)}}{\partial X}
$$

This is what I know.

Now, let us look at the multitask loss function as follows:

$$J = \lambda_1 Y_1 + \lambda_2 Y_2$$

where $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are outputs of the DNN with external trainable parameters $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_1$.

The weight updation is as usual. And I think the updation of external trainable parameters is as follows:
$$\frac{\partial{J}}{\partial{\lambda_1}}=Y_1$$
$$\frac{\partial{J}}{\partial{\lambda_2}}=Y_2$$

Is that correct? Is it that simple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Makes no sense to have those $\lambda$ as trainable, because the optimizer will just use them to minimize the loss.

For example, take $Y_1 = \text{MSE}$ and $Y_2 = \text{MAE}$, then the loss will always be $\ge 0$... minimizing a loss means finding a minimum... if you use any optimizer on that loss, you will see that he will set the $\lambda$ to $-\infty$ an will maximize the MSE and the MAE... in other words, you won't get any good result out of this

OT:

- In your forward pass, you are missing an affine transformation
- your gradient is not differentiating with respect to $W_1$

Comment: Ok, it was my mistake. I tried to oversimplify the loss function. For example, in this case the $\lambda$ won't go to negative infinity. I was just curious how this derivative thing actually works behind the scene.  https://forums.fast.ai/t/loss-function-with-learnable-parameters/65301/5

Comment: @PrakharSharma yes, you can just differentiate like you did in the question, however you usually has to impose a prior over those trainable hyperparameter, like they did in the question you linked with the last term